# regex to identify inline style attributes in the HTML tag

Tags: java, regex

From the html source file i've to identify tag with inline style attribute using java.

For example

```
<span id="abc" 
 style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:'arial black','sans-serif'; color:#5f497a">
```

Please help

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex is one way to do it, eg.

```
/<span[^>]*style=.*?>/
```

Or alternatively, if the HTML is well formed, load it using a parser and then use an XPath.

```
//span[@style]
```

Comment: not only for span tag style attribute may present in any block elements

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Do not parse HTML with regex. Use a proper HTML parser (there are tons out there for Java), and extract the desired data from the DOM tree.